# gcc-4.8 Header files

Tags: 13.10, gcc

I am having some trouble using the header files provided by gcc-4.8 since updating to Ubuntu 13.10. When I compile with the Intel compiler `icc`, it complains about not being able to find the header file `bits/c++config.h`. This file is located in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits` but the intel compiler is looking in `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits`. The file `c++config.h` is not in this second location.

I realize that I can work around this issue by including the first directory while compiling. My question is why are these two directories not the same:

`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits`

`/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits`

Files for these directories are shown [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/libstdc++-4.8-dev/filelist) in the libstdc++-4.8-dev package.